# Limitar links a serem exibidos na paginação PHP e Bootstrap

Tags: php, paginação

Bom dia! Gostaria de uma ajuda para limitar a quantidade de links e serem exibidos na paginação. Meus links são exibidos assim:

Anterior 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Próximo

Pra quantidade de links não ficar muito grande, gostaria que ficasse assim:

Anterior 1 2 ... Próximo

Anterior ... 3 4 5 ... Próximo

Anterior ... 6 7 Próximo

Meu código php + bootstrap:

```
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$sql_pagina = "SELECT * FROM posts";     
$result_pagina = $conexao->prepare($sql_pagina);
$result_pagina->execute();
$numTotal = $result_pagina->rowCount();

$quantidade = 5;

$num_pagina = ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);

$inicio = ($pagina * $quantidade) - $quantidade;

...
código HMTL
...

<?php
$pagina_anterior = $pagina -1;
$pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
?>
<nav align="center" aria-label="Page navigation" class="nav-pagination" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <ul class="pagination">
       <li>
       <?php 
       if($pagina_anterior != 0) { ?>
          <a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true">Anterior</span>
          </a>
       <?php } else { ?>
             <span aria-hidden="true">Anterior</span>
       <?php } ?>
       </li>
       <?php 
           for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
                    <li><a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
       <?php } ?>
       <li>
           <?php 
           if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) { ?>
              <a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">Próximo</span>
              </a>
           <?php } else { ?>
              <span aria-hidden="true">Próximo</span>
            <?php } ?>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa do `for` para fazer isso, pois você definiu as variáveis `pagina_anterior` e `pagina_posterior`.

Substitua esse for:

```
<?php 
   for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
   <li><a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

por isso:

```
<?php 
if($pagina > 2){
    echo "<li><span>...</span></li>"; // a partir da página 3 será necessário colocar os 3 pontos
}

if($pagina > 1)
echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina_anterior."'>".$pagina_anterior."</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina."'>".$pagina."</a></li>";
if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina)
echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina_posterior ."'>".$pagina_posterior."</a></li>";

if($pagina_posterior < $num_pagina){
    echo "<li><span>...</span></li>"; // se a próxima página for igual ultima página não será necessário colocar os 3 pontos
}
?>
```

Seu código ficará assim: **(EDIT)**

```
<?php 

$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$sql_pagina = "SELECT * FROM posts";     
$result_pagina = $conexao->prepare($sql_pagina);
$result_pagina->execute();
$numTotal = $result_pagina->rowCount();

$quantidade = 5;

$num_pagina = ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);

$inicio = ($pagina * $quantidade) - $quantidade;
?>
...
código HMTL
...

<?php
$pagina_anterior = $pagina -1;
$pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
?>
<nav align="center" aria-label="Page navigation" class="nav-pagination" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<ul class="pagination">
   <li>
   <?php 
   if($pagina_anterior != 0) { ?>
      <a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
         <span aria-hidden="true">Anterior</span>
      </a>
   <?php } else { ?>
         <span aria-hidden="true">Anterior</span>
   <?php } ?>
   </li>
   <?php
        if($pagina > 2){
            echo "<li><span aria-hidden='true'>...</li>";
        }
        if($pagina > 1){
        echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina_anterior."'>".$pagina_anterior."</a></li>";
        }
        echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina."'>".$pagina."</a></li>";
        if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){
            echo "<li><a href='http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=".$pagina_posterior ."'>".$pagina_posterior."</a></li>"; 
        }
        if($pagina_posterior < $num_pagina){
            echo "<li><span aria-hidden='true'>...</li>";
        }
        ?>
   <li>
       <?php 
       if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) { ?>
          <a href="http://www.arturluz.com/?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true">Próximo</span>
          </a>
       <?php } else { ?>
          <span aria-hidden="true">Próximo</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Olá Andrei! Fiz a troca mas a exibição ficou algo assim:  Anterior 1 2 Próximo ...         Anterior 1 2 3 Próximo ...       Anterior 2 3 4 Próximo ...      Anterior 3 4 Próximo ...     . Os três pontinhos ficou fora do nav do bootstrap.

Comment: @RodrigoSouzaJesus vou verificar

Comment: @RodrigoSouzaJesus verifique se o seu código ficou igual ao que eu editei

Comment: coloque um `<span>` nos 3 pontinhos

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. Como é bom ter ajuda de pessoas como você, obrigado! Aqui está o resultado no link http://www.arturluz.com/.

Comment: você entende sobre url amigável? se sim, pode me mandar seu email?